# WF4 - resuming from instance store and InstanceNotReadyException

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am using WF4 and the WorkflowApplication to host a workflow. The workflow is very simple (at testing stage). It boils down to a series of logging activities with a delay activity and then more logging before finishing. I am using SqlWorkflowInstanceStore for saving persisting the workflows.

The workflow runs fine until it reaches the delay activity, here I can see that it gets saved into the persist database and then unloaded. I have looked at code examples and use the current code (at bottom) for resuming the workflow after the delay has expired. The code is run in a loop to ensure new (resumable) workflows are loaded. It all seems to work fine, the workflow gets resumed and I can se the expected logging output - however after the workflow completes it seems to try to resume it again. The call

```
WaitForEvents(_handle, TimeSpan.MaxValue)
```

contiunes again just like its going to resume a completed workflow. Next the

```
hasRunnableWorkflows
```

gets set to true. When the code reaches

```
wfApp.LoadRunnableInstance();
```

The exception `InstanceNotReadyException (No runnable workflow instances were found in the InstanceStore for this WorkflowApplication to load.)` is thrown.

I dont understand why this is happening and how to prevent the exception getting thrown. If I ignore the exception everything seems to work fine but I want to know why this is happening and if I'm doing someting wrong.

Code for resuming the workflow:

```
    public Task ResumePendingFlows()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Guid>();
        var store = _workflowInstanceStore?.Store;

        if (store != null)
        {
            bool hasRunnableWorkflows = false;

            //wait until a event has occurred
            foreach (var currentEvent in store.WaitForEvents(_handle, TimeSpan.MaxValue))
            {
                if (currentEvent == HasRunnableWorkflowEvent.Value)
                {
                    hasRunnableWorkflows = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (hasRunnableWorkflows)
            {
                //create WorkflowApplication with extensions and instance store
                var wfApp = CreateWorkflowApplication();

                    wfApp.LoadRunnableInstance();
                    Logger?.Debug("Found runnable workflows");
                    //register completed, unloaded event passing the task completion source
                    RegisterWorkflowEvents(tcs, wfApp);
                    wfApp.Run();
            }
            else
            {
                Logger?.Debug("Did not find runnable workflows");
                tcs.SetResult(Guid.Empty);
            }
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: have you found something new about InstanceNotReadyException ? Do you create store with the same name for certain workflow definition or using something like Guid.New when store name is assigned? I have similar problem and it looks very strange that error InstanceNotReadyException is raised for wfIDs that are not exist in the persistent [InstancesTable]. Could you please share yours experience ?

Comment: I never got rid of the exception - however it seems to work if you just ignore it.

In the end, I went for MassTransit saga (statemachine) instead of WF.